# Let gcc call a specific function between c operations

Tags: c++, c, gcc, assembly, compiler-construction

I am trying to make a watchdog for a single-threaded program. The problem is, that we run some foreign so/dlls (the code is available) which means that we pass control there.

The idea is to recompile these with some callback to a sort of a cancellation routine.

Is it possible to let GCC call some callback functions in between of C-transactions or asm-transactions in this compiled foreign code?

Comment: The answer to this SO post explains how to get gcc to inject debug calls per function enter and exit. Might well be what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281739/automatically-adding-enter-exit-function-logs-to-a-project

Comment: that goes into the right direction, however i need some more calls e.g. in the loops

Comment: What exactly is a "C-transaction"?

Comment: @Stasik: I'm pretty certain that what you want to do is not possible with GCC. If you're happy to use [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) and write a plugin to add the calls, then you can probably do what you need. But that sounds like a lot of work...

Comment: @Keith: I do not know a proper explanation for a set of ASM commands that are generated from one C statement like "a=a+1;" are actually several ASM commands.

Comment: @AlexWilson it looks like that, this is sad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm about to suggest does not involve the compiler, but this sounds like a problem you can solve at runtime with POSIX signals or [`ptrace`](http://www.google.com/search?q=ptrace) ...

With a signal you can interrupt the current context, similar to what would happen in kernel mode with an IRQ.  You will have to worry about being "signal-safe" (example: your handler can't use `malloc` because it might interrupt `malloc` itself while its data structures are in an indeterminate state.)

With `ptrace` you can step through instructions in another process as if in a debugger.

Tread carefully, as these are difficult mechanisms to use correctly and it's very easy to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: POSIX is a not real alternative since we use mixed windows/linux environments :(

Comment: @Stasik In that case you'll probably need radically different approaches for each..  Have you looked at `QueueUserAPC`?  `WaitForDebugEvent`?

Comment: yep, ptrace seems to be a way of realizing it, however, I actually was looking for a single-threaded solution.

Comment: @Stasik - The code in question will still run on a single thread, even if your control code is running in another process or thread.  The way I see it you're rejecting workable solutions if favor of something that doesn't make sense at all.  (Who knows if your original problem maps well onto this question?  Maybe you should take a step back and re-evaluate what it is you want to do.)

Comment: this is true, however we often do run on uC's, meaning there is no way of having a watchdog thread. Still, you might be right with the ugly way I would do it. Okay us assume, I take POSIX signals, is there a way to force a program to smash the stack and return from the current function it is stack in an interrupt handler e.g. for the ALARM signal? (not to speak about memory leaks ;)).

Comment: the answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9968148/is-it-possible-to-give-a-processor-execution-time-for-certain-functions-in-c