# How can I print each function name as the function is called in C++?

Tags: c++, function, debugging

I am exploring a large code-base and i am not a gdb fan. I would like add a 
`LOG(INFO) << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__` in the first line of each function in the code-base. But that's very tedious. Does anyone know a hack to make all function calls to print a LOG message with its function name?

Comment: I believe GCC lets you install a function to be called at the beginning of every other function.

Comment: can write small script to do that.

Comment: I doubt you actually want this; the output will be so verbose & ugly it won't be helpful. Why not use a dedicated profiling tool to instrument this for you, or go at it from the other direction like Dieter's solution below?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically adding Enter/Exit Function Logs to a Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281739/automatically-adding-enter-exit-function-logs-to-a-project)

Answer (score 3):

I do something similar to:

```
#include <iostream>

class LogScope
{
    public:
    LogScope(const char* scope, const char* file, int line = 0)
    :   m_scope(scope), m_file(file), m_line(line)
    {
        std::clog << "[Begin] " << m_scope << ", " << m_file << ", " << m_line << std::endl;
    }

    ~LogScope() {
        std::clog << "[End]   "  << m_scope << ", " << m_file << ", " << m_line << std::endl;
    }

    private:
    const char* m_scope;
    const char* m_file;
    int m_line;
};

#define NAME_AT_LINE_2(Name, Line) Name##_##Line
#define NAME_AT_LINE_1(Name, Line) NAME_AT_LINE_2(Name, Line)
#define NAME_AT_LINE(Name) NAME_AT_LINE_1(Name, __LINE__)

#define LOG_SCOPE \
    ::LogScope NAME_AT_LINE(log_scope)(__FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__)

void f() {
    LOG_SCOPE;
}

int main() {
    LOG_SCOPE;
    f();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems a duplicate of [Automatically adding Enter/Exit Function Logs to a Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281739/automatically-adding-enter-exit-function-logs-to-a-project)

However, You can consider using gprof that has the capability to generate a runtime call tree. You can have dot graphs, which might be easier to read.