# how to target reliably functions when pre-processing C/C++ code with sed or awk?

Tags: c++, c, regex, awk, sed

I want to instrument my code directly by pre-processing source files with sed/awk. I cannot use other methods like debugger traces or gcc option `-finstrument-functions`. In this last case, the addresses are rebased in some way I cannot manage and I miss the correspondence with the symbol table. Other methods presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/311840/tool-to-trace-local-function-calls-in-linux) (ptrace, etrace, callgraph, etc) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2281739/automatically-adding-enter-exit-function-logs-to-a-project) work well on a simple example, but not in my real project.

The problem is that when processing big open source projects, the writing standards of functions differ, not only between C and C++ files, but often in the same file. The `{` may be at the end of the argument list, or on the other line, structures or assignment may use a starting `{`, making simple function parsing false.

So the solution presented in the above links that insert a macro in the beginning of the function definition does not work in general, and it is not feasible to correct by hand kilo lines of code (KLOC).

```
sed 's/^{/{ENTRY/'
```

So, how to target reliably functions definitions in C/C++ code with regular expressions usable in sed or awk? Possibly by using a part of the gcc precompiler code? I am looking for something possibly off-the -shelf please.

Answer (score 8):

`sed` or `awk` (or any purely textual approach) are the wrong tools to process *reliably* C code (and you probably should work on the pre-processed form).

You want to work on some form of the compiler's [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Of course the internal representations inside a compiler are specific to the compiler (and perhaps even to its version).

If using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) you could customize it using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (and add your passes to GCC) -or with your own plugin in C++.

If using [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) you could also customize it by adding your passes.

The [Coccinelle](http://coccinelle.lip6.fr/) tool might also be relevant.

Any such approach requires a significant amount of work (probably weeks) since you'll need to understand in detail the internal representations of the particular compiler you are using. And C is complex enough to make that non-trivial.

Comment: [LibClang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html) and Python bindings might also be an option as a preprocessor - use the parsing functionality of Clang, modify the AST as required, then output C++ source corresponding to the modified AST again, and finally run normal Clang on this source file.

Comment: MELT looks great and a top solution, but the learning curve is to high for my immediate need.

Comment: But *all* the approaches require you to understand the internals of your compiler (and its ASTs). This is the major difficulty. Hence the "weeks of effort".

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with any tool that does not understand the specific version of C your code is written in (e.g. C++ or ANSI-C or C-99). As a trivial example - what does "//" mean in a "C function"? Well if it's inside a string it's a literal pair of slashes, and if it's outside of a string it might be the start of a comment if the code is C++ or C-99 but its not the start of a comment in ANSI-C. What if it's inside `/* ... // ... */`? If what looks like a function definition follows a "//" is that really a function?

You don't say what it is you want to do ("pre-process the code" doesn't tell us anything) but you should look into using something like I posted at [Remove multi-line comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13061785/remove-multi-line-comments) to use gcc to strip code of comments and then a C beautifier like "indent" or "cb" to reformat the code consistently and/or take a look at "cscope" or "ccalls" if you're just looking for a tool to list functions.

Comment: In the beginning of my post, I talk of traces with trial with -finstrument-functions and other methods, with links. That means I want to add usefull information traces in the code, not strip it.

Comment: It doesn't mean that to me. I've no idea what `-finstrument-functions` means or why you were talking about debugger traces. Are you saying you want to add print statements to your code when functions are entered/exited or something else? If so, what do you want those print statements to output? You are missing the point of my post - I'm not telling you how to strip the code, I'm telling you how to re-format it in a consistent way so that you CAN write/use a tool to find function starts, etc.